# EPplus To Insert X Number of Blank Rows

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

I have an instance where if a cell value is between 15 and 25  then I need to insert 10 blank rows, if the cell value is > 30 I need to insert 25 blank rows

Rather than simply typing the same syntax repeatedly and adding 1 row at a time, does EPPLUS have a function of adding X rows at one time?

This works but will be lots of code repeated:

```
ws.InsertRow(31, 31, 1);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The method you are using already takes care of that.

```
w.InsertRow(10, 15);
```

This will insert 15 rows starting at row 10. All the rows under will be shifted down.

The actual method signature:`public void InsertRow(int rowFrom, int rows);`